# School HomeWork- Bank account - cursor

Tags: database, oracle, cursor

This is homework question.

```
Customer(customer_id, customer_name, address, phone)
Account(bank_name, account_num, balance)
Has-Account(customer_id, bank_name, account_num)
```

I am trying to write a cursor that for each customer returns the customer’s id, name, phone number, bank’s name, and the sum of the customer’s accounts per each bank.

```
CURSOR cust_balance IS
    SELECT
```

What I tried:

```
Select customer_id, customer_name, phone, bank_name, count(account_num) over (partition by bank_name) from Customer, 
Account , Has-Account where Customer.customer_id = Has-Account.customer_id 
AND Account.account_num = Has-Account.account_num and Account.bank_name = Has-Account.bank_name
```

How do I calculate sum of the customer’s accounts per each bank in this query ?

Comment: after bank_name add count(*) over (partition by bank_name) as cust_in_bank.

Answer (score 0):

To use a cursor, you would need to declare a variable to store each field that you were interested in. Although this is possible, it may be easier to use an aggregate function, grouping by customer_id and some bank field. Have you tried this already, or does the assignment strictly require the use of a cursor. Generally speaking, it's better to handle this sort of operation in a SELECT than it is a cursor script.

I believe the following code should work for you, but I don't have a DB Engine available to test it out on. You can certainly look up using the SUM function on w3 schools, but I believe it is common to most SQL platforms:

```
SELECT
C.customer_name,
A.bank_name,
SUM(a.balance)  AS 'balance'
FROM Customer AS c 
    INNER JOIN Has-Account AS ha ON c.customer_id = ha.customer_id
    INNER JOIN Account AS a ON (
        ha.bank_name = a.bank_name AND ha.account_num = a.account_num
    )
GROUP BY C.customer_id
```

Comment: this is to calculate sum of accounts per each bank  or sum of balances per each bank ?

Comment: This would be to calculate the sum of all open accounts that a customer has. If you want to SUM all the balances that the BANK has, it's actually much simpler:

SELECT bank_name, SUM(balance) AS 'balance' FROM Account GROUP BY bank_name, account_num.